# Having trouble with an auto updater

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am new to coding in access and I came across a simple way to update a database remotely. Attached is the directions and a stripped down version of my database. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!!

> This is a great module that works wonderful, but I wanted to let
>   people know you can do the version checking without using VBA, and
>   simply have an Updater application that runs the VBA to delete your
>   local copy and download the fresh version off the server.
>
> I use a table called AppConstants on the server's backend that has two
>   columns: ConstantTitle and ConstantValue. One of the rows has
>   ConstantTitle set to "AppVersion" and ConstantValue set to the version
>   number.
>
> Then I have a field with visibility set to False on my main form
>   called VersionNo, and I set this field's value to ="VersionNumber"
>   (where VersionNumber is the actual version number, e.g. ="1.25"). On
>   the Main Form's OnLoad event, I have a macro that runs a DLookup in an
>   IF command:
>
> ```
>  if DLookUp("[ConstantValue]", "tblAdmin", "[ConstantTitle] ='AppVersion'")<>[Forms]![frmMain]![VersionNo] Then RunCode OpenUpdater()
>  Quit Access
>  End If
>
> The code for OpenUpdater: 
> Code:
> Function OpenUpdater()  'This sets the name of the code to call later
> Dim accapp As Access.Application
> Set accapp = New Access.Application
> accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\$Data\MyUpdater.accde")  'Starts up this file
> accapp.Visible = True
> End Function
> ```
>
> What it's doing: The macro checks the value of the VersionNumber in the table on the server. When I update the app copy
>   on the server, I set a new version number in here and set my app
>   copy's VersionNo field to the same number. When you're running the old
>   version, your app sees that the version numbers don't match, and then
>   it executes the Macro's 'Then' commands: it runs the OpenUpdater code
>   and shuts itself off.
>
> The OpenUpdater code simply starts the MyUpdater.accde program, which
>   is by default installed on the user's PC along with the application
>   itself. The OpenUpdater program executes the following
>   code:
>      DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarNo
>
> ```
> 'Copy the new version to the C drive
>  Dim SourceFile, DestinationFile As String
>  SourceFile = "Z:\Server\MyProgram.accde"   'Where to get the fresh copy
>  DestinationFile = "C:\$Data\MyProgram.accde"   'Where to put it
>  With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
>  .copyfile SourceFile, DestinationFile, True    'This line does the acual  copy and paste
>  End With
>
>  'Reopen MyProgram
>  Dim accapp As Access.Application
>  Set accapp = New Access.Application
>  accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase ("C:\$Data\MyProgram.accde")
>  accapp.Visible = True
>  End Function
> ```
>
> This Function is called in a Macro within MyUpdater, and the command just after the RunCode in this Macro is QuitAccess,
>   which shuts off the Updater.
>
> So my main program, when you open the main form, checks the version
>   number on the server. If they're different, the main program starts
>   the updater and then shuts itself down. The updater copies the fresh
>   version off the server and pastes it in the correct place on the C
>   drive, then starts up the program and shuts itself down.
>
> From the end-user's perspective, the program starts, immediately
>   quits, and then starts again a second or so later and now it's
>   updated. It works awesome.

My issue is when I open up the copy database, the update doesn't run
but it runs when I go into the myupdater database and manually run the
macro. Here is the macro

```
If DLookUp("[ConstantValue]","AppConstants","[ConstantTitle]='AppVersion'")<>[Forms]![NavMain]![VersionNo]
Then RunCode FunctionName OpenUpdater() 
Quit   Access
```

Here is the function

```
Function OpenUpdater()  'This sets the name of the code to call later
Dim accapp As Access.Application
Set accapp = New Access.Application
accapp.OpenCurrentDatabase  ("C:\Users\Tyrone\Desktop\MyUpdater.accde")  'Starts up this file
accapp.Visible = True
End Function
```

Comment: You can't attach Access files here. Instead, describe the problem. It's currently unclear what you're asking. Please try and provide a [mcve]. You state you have an issue, but you're not telling us anything about that issue.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I added it in the edits

Comment: It is much easier to run a script: [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application with one click](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33417/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-with-one-click.html)

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is similar to what I use. I also used script approach but I liked having all in Access and not having to install script file on each user machine. However, I did not use macro, only VBA. The VBA is behind a Login form that opens by default. Form is bound to Updates table so DLookup() is not used for the version check. gstrBasePath is a global constant declared in a general module. This uses Windows Shell so it is necessary to set reference to Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation library. Unfortunately, IT updated computers with additional restrictions that won't allow programmatic copy of files at all (was originally limited to C:\ root location) and this no longer works for me.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

'Check for updates to the program on start up - if values don't match then there is a later version
If Me.tbxVersion <> Me.lblVersion.Caption Then
    'because administrator opens the master development copy, only run this for non-administrator users
    If DLookup("Permissions", "Users", "UserNetworkID='" & Environ("UserName") & "'") <> "admin" Then
        'copy Access file
        CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CopyFile _
            gstrBasePath & "Program\Install\MaterialsDatabase.accdb", "c:\", True
        'allow enough time for file to completely copy before opening
        Dim Start As Double
        Start = Timer
        While Timer < Start + 3
            DoEvents
        Wend
        'load new version - SysCmd function gets the Access executable file path
        'Shell function requires literal quote marks in the target filename string argument, apostrophe delimiters fail, hence the quadrupled quote marks
        Shell SysCmd(acSysCmdAccessDir) & "MSAccess.exe " & """" & CurrentProject.FullName & """", vbNormalFocus
        'close current file
        DoCmd.Quit
    End If
Else
    'tbxVersion available only to administrator to update version number in Updates table
    Me.tbxVersion.Visible = False
    Call UserLogin
End If

End Sub

Private Sub tbxUser_AfterUpdate()
If Me.tbxUser Like "[A-z][A-z][A-z]" Or Me.tbxUser Like "[A-z][A-z]" Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Users(UserNetworkID, UserInitials, Permissions) VALUES('" & VBA.Environ("UserName") & "', '" & UCase(Me.tbxUser) & "', 'staff')"
    Call UserLogin
Else
    MsgBox "Not an appropriate entry.", vbApplicationModal, "EntryError"
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserLogin()
Me.tbxUser = DLookup("UserInitials", "Users", "UserNetworkID='" & Environ("UserName") & "'")
If Not IsNull(Me.tbxUser) Then
    CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE Users SET ComputerName='" & VBA.Environ("ComputerName") & "' WHERE UserInitials='" & Me.tbxUser & "'"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "Menu", acNormal, , "UserInitials='" & Me.tbxUser & "'", , acWindowNormal
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name, acSaveNo
End If
End Sub
```